# Xcodebuild Test operation failure

Tags: ios, xcode, appium, xcodebuild, appium-ios

I'm trying to use the new version of appium with the XCUITEST method for ipad testing. Once I start the Appium server (1.6.0 Beta2) and execute my tests (using Java with Cucumber) I get several errors from appium log.

> [Xcode] 2016-10-06 12:18:25.074 xcodebuild[5380:983002] Error
>   Domain=IDETestOperationsObserverErrorDomain Code=3 "Test operation was
>   canceled. If you believe this error represents a bug, please attach
>   the log file at
>   /Users/gchaikin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-brdadhpuduowllgivnnvuygpwhzy/Logs/Test/55FF83B2-8215-4D5A-BE53-A44661B07463/Session-WebDriverAgentRunner-2016-10-06_121824-SUJrDx.log"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Test operation was canceled. If you
>   believe this error represents a bug, please attach the log file at
>   /Users/gchaikin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-brdadhpuduowllgivnnvuygpwhzy/Logs/Test/55FF83B2-8215-4D5A-BE53-A44661B07463/Session-WebDriverAgentRunner-2016-10-06_121824-SUJrDx.log}

The log above contains only the same information.

Then it says

> [Xcode] 2016-10-06 12:18:25.077 xcodebuild[5380:983070] Connection
>   peer refused channel request for
>   "dtxproxy:XCTestManager_IDEInterface:XCTestManager_DaemonConnectionInterface";
>   channel canceled
>
> [Xcode] Testing failed:   ./Scripts/generate_modules.sh: line 15:
>   Modules/module.modulemap: Permission denied
>   ** TEST FAILED ** The following build commands failed:    PhaseScriptExecution Generate\ modules
>   /Users/gchaikin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-brdadhpuduowllgivnnvuygpwhzy/Build/Intermediates/WebDriverAgent.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WebDriverAgentLib.build/Script-AD35D0281CF1B37A00870A75.sh
>   (1 failure)
>
> [XCUITest] xcodebuild exited with code '65' and signal 'null'

The WebDriverAgent log says the next

> 11:58:36.481 xcodebuild[4014:965497] Launching with
>   Xcode.IDEFoundation.Launcher.PosixSpawn 11:58:36.482
>   xcodebuild[4014:965497] Initializing test infrastructure. 11:58:36.483
>   xcodebuild[4014:965498] 2DCCFAF0-AC2A-41F2-ADCF-80A64E869EA7:
>   Registered for sim device notification, got token 4 11:58:36.483
>   xcodebuild[4014:965498] 2DCCFAF0-AC2A-41F2-ADCF-80A64E869EA7:
>   Unregistering for sim device notification with token 4 11:58:36.483
>   xcodebuild[4014:965498] Sim iPad Air 2 is booted (state = 3)
>   11:58:36.483 xcodebuild[4014:965498] Calling -[SimDevice
>   getenv:error:] for TESTMANAGERD_SIM_SOCK 11:58:36.484
>   xcodebuild[4014:965498] Returning
>   /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.FQMBCMNTix/com.apple.testmanagerd.unix-domain.socket
>   for TESTMANAGERD_SIM_SOCK 11:58:36.484 xcodebuild[4014:965498] Sim
>   iPad Air 2 has testmanagerd socket at
>   /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.FQMBCMNTix/com.apple.testmanagerd.unix-domain.socket
>   11:58:36.484 xcodebuild[4014:965498] Connected socket 33 to
>   testmanagerd for Sim iPad Air 2 11:58:36.484 xcodebuild[4014:965498]
>   Creating the test bundle connection. 11:58:36.485
>   xcodebuild[4014:965498] Listening for proxy connection request from
>   the test bundle (all platforms) 11:58:36.485 xcodebuild[4014:965498]
>   Resuming the connection. 11:58:36.486 xcodebuild[4014:965498] Test
>   connection requires daemon assistance. 11:58:36.487
>   xcodebuild[4014:965497] Received Ready from iOSSimulator 11:58:36.487
>   xcodebuild[4014:965497] Sending notification: NSConcreteNotification
>   0x7fda73f2d5a0 {name = com.apple.iphonesimulator.startSession;
>   userInfo = {
>       deviceUDID = "2DCCFAF0-AC2A-41F2-ADCF-80A64E869EA7"; }} 11:58:36.509 xcodebuild[4014:965497] Starting test session with ID
>   <__NSConcreteUUID 0x7fda743188b0> 2FBA9011-A9DC-40E3-85F3-3260DDE41977
>   11:58:36.509 xcodebuild[4014:965497] Checking test manager
>   availability..., will wait up to 120s 11:58:36.721
>   xcodebuild[4014:965497] Test operation failure: Test operation was
>   canceled. 11:58:36.721 xcodebuild[4014:965497] _finishWithError:Error
>   Domain=IDETestOperationsObserverErrorDomain Code=3 "Test operation was
>   canceled." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Test operation was
>   canceled.} didCancel: 1

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: have you found a solution to this yet?

Answer (score 0):

Well after updating the appium server to 1.6.0 beta 3, the issue was resolved. Now I'm on the stable 1.6.0 version and I'm facing a whole different problem. The app I'm testing is in Landscape mode and I cannot have appium clicking or tapping on any of the elements.

Did anyone hear this issue?

Comment: Hi @genatron,
You should mark the first sentence of this answer as the answer, and then cut the rest of the text above and post it as a separate question here on Stack Overflow. It's more likely you'll find someone who can help that way ;)